# understanding the anatomy of file formats and image formats

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am trying to do some research on file formats especially image formats. Information such as header layouts for particular types of image formats and how to parse them using C++. If anyone can point me in the right direction of some good tutorials or books. that would be helpful. thanks

[edit]
If there are any resources on the general layout of a file format and what and what not to look out for in formats that will be beneficial as well

Comment: Your best bet is to go find the standards and specifications that define the formats in which you are interested.

Comment: find the standards and specifications ?? is there any place in particular ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An indispensible source of information in this regard http://www.wotsit.org .

You can also  find some good info at the [Amiga File Formats](http://lclevy.free.fr/amiga/formats.html) page (don't get misled by the "Amiga" in the title -- many of those formats are still used, and it's a great source of information).

Also, a good source of information is [magicdb.org](http://www.magicdb.org/), where you might especially be interested in the [designing a new file format](http://www.magicdb.org/filedesign.html) page. However, before you do that, be sure to check out the general purpose formats like AIFF, TIFF, IFF and RIFF -- one might suit your need, and there's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: wow, wotsit is a great website. Ok follow up questions. Do you know of any place that discusses file formats in general. Such as common attributes you will find in file format and how to interpret and use them. Or just a general tutorial on understanding file formats.

Comment: @numerical25, I expanded my answer ;)